# How to filter the inbox in JMeter Mail reader sampler?

Tags: jmeter

How can I filter the message in the JMeter Mail reader sampler based on the Subject in the gmail? The gmail inbox will have many emails with different subjects and I want to read only the messages with a particular subject.

Apart from creating subfolders and apply rules, is there any other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of current version of [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) this is not possible, you can try raising an enhancement request in [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html), however you will have to wait for at least next major version to get this functionality.

As a workaround you can switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which allows executing arbitrary code so you will be able to use [Folder.search()](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#search-javax.mail.search.SearchTerm-) function and read only the messages which have a specified substring in the Subject.

Example code:

```
props.setProperty('mail.transport.protocol', 'imaps')
props.setProperty('mail.imap.host', 'imap.gmail.com')
props.setProperty('mail.imap.port', '995')
props.setProperty('mail.imap.ssl.enable', 'true');

def session = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
store = session.getStore('imaps')
store.connect('imap.gmail.com', 'your-username@gmail.com', 'your-password')
inbox = store.getFolder('INBOX')
inbox.open(javax.mail.Folder.READ_ONLY)
def messages = inbox.search(new javax.mail.search.SubjectTerm('your-search-term'))
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Not able to see the message in the response body. I want to take some values from the response (email message).

Comment: Man, I don't know how many messages matching the search criteria will be returned and what is the message format (plain text, or HTML), if there are any attachments, etc. The easiest is adding something like `SampleResult.setResponseData(messages.first().getContent() as String, 'UTF-8')` to the end of your script, it may or may not be sufficient. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on what does this `SampleResult` mean and what are other shorthands

Comment: Thank you. Adding this giving me the message. Is there any way to search this message? For example, I want to get the below code (different code to different message) to a variable from the response message.
code=3907a949-8453-4ce9-b360-26027bddb845&amp;locale=en_US

Comment: I tried with regular expression extractor but not working.